# get horizontal scroll bar instead of cutting off winform when made smaller

Tags: winforms, layout, scrollbar, controls, panel

I'm using a winform. When I set the width to a little too small, or user adjusts my form width, some of my controls are getting cut off. The behavior that I'm looking for is a horizontal scroll bar appearing in this situation.

The issue is with the top panel of my form. This is my setup.

I have a panel - Dock = Top
In it, I have one panel (pnlHeaderLeft) - Dock = Left and another panel (pnlHeaderRight) - Dock = Right

In pnlHeaderLeft, I have a drop down and 2 buttons with anchor = top, left.
In pnlHeaderRight, I have a devex layout control with Dock=fill.

Can an expert pls assist?

Comment: Did you set the AutoScroll property of the Panel container? That should be enough to get a Scroll bar when you resize the form

Comment: I don't want a scroll bar on my panel, I want one on the bottom of the form.

Comment: Your form will never scroll because your panels are docked, which means they are pinned to their sides.

Comment: Can you help me do this without dock?